# source.list wrong by default in wily werewolf

Tags: upgrade, software-sources, 15.10

I just upgraded to wily werewolf beta. It seems that by default, my sources.list (here's the file: http://pastebin.com/FE0NyzNk) contains something wrong. I get 404 error when doing update when connecting to some of the sources. For some reason many of them seem to be located at old-releases.ubuntu.com.

I generated a new source.list file from this website, http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/, and now everything seems to work. However, if I touch settings in software & updates tool, it again adds crap to the file.

Is this a bug or do I have some old broken sources.list stored somewhere and the tool is trying to get the default entries from there or what?

EDIT: output of `lsb_release -a` is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Wily Werewolf (development branch)
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: OK, here it is.

Comment: And when you start `Software & Updates`, without doing anything, the items are added again?

Comment: Not if I don't do anything. Only if I change something, i.e. uncheck and then re-check one of the software sources.

Comment: Perhaps that wasn't so clear so here's a clarification. When I open the tool (with manually corrected sources.list), nothing happens. If I go to other software tab, it shows empty. If I go to ubuntu software tab then and change something, then old-releases crap gets added to the sources.list again.

Comment: Ok, that's a bug, Wiliy isn't released yet. Wait some days.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the entries `old-releases` via

   ```
   sudo sed -i '/old-releases/d' /etc/apt-sources.list
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Don't use the tab <kbd>Updates</kbd> in <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd> until Wily is released in some days.